# Mixing of two arrays

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I need some help here. Recently started to learn programming and I ran across the task I got problems with. The task is: There are two arrays of objects and number of steps. Goal is to merge them and then in every step if two objects from different array meet, you swap them, but they each go only one direction. I don't need implementation, just help with algorithm.

```
array 1: A,B,C
array 2: 1,2,3 (Those two arrays can be larger than 3 objects each and don't have
 to be same length)
merged array: A,B,C,1,2,3
number of steps:5
```

Step 1:A,B,1,C,2,3

Step 2:A,1,B,2,C,3

Step 3:1,A,2,B,3,C

Step 4:1,2,A,3,B,C

Step 5:1,2,3,A,B,C

My attempt was :

```
public void Move(int steps)
    { for (int i = 0; i<steps; i++)
        {for (int j = 0; j<mergedArray.size()-1; j++){
        if (!mergedArray.get(j).getType().equals(mergedArray.get(j+1).getType()))
                { Collections.swap(mergedArray, j, j+1);
                j++;
                }
        }
    }
```

But that works only for half of steps.

Thanks for any help!

Edit:Fixed array boundary in code

Answer (score 0):

One issue I'm seeing is that your for loop is going to run into trouble. You've got `for(int j = 0; j < mergedArray.size(); j++) { ... }`, and inside the loop you have `mergedArray.get(j+1)`, so you'll hit an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` pretty fast if you're not careful. Other than that, looks reasonable, I implemented a similar one and it split stuff as it should.

Answer (score -1):

It wont be the fastest algorithm but should work.
You have 2 loops :

1st : You iterate unit you reach number of steps, you have a good implementation here.
2nd : Just after elements from arrays meet you need to stop iteration in this loop. Use continue.